# Get MAC address from client's machine

Tags: php, networking, syntax, shell-exec, mac-address

I'm new to this, and I did some searching, but most of the answers have the same results: the MAC address output is shown as "Found."

My code is below:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$mac=shell_exec("arp -a ".$ip);
$mac_string = shell_exec("arp -a $ip");
$mac_array = explode(" ",$mac_string);
$mac = $mac_array[3];

if(empty($mac)) {
   die("No mac address for $ip not found");
}

echo($ip." - ".$mac);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, the old `exec()` vs `shell_exec()` vs `passthru()` question.

To see what command is *actually* being run, and what the system is *actually* returning, use `exec()`, and pass it an `int` and an `array` as its 2nd and 3rd params respectively, then `var_dump()` them both after running the command.

For example:

```
$cmd = "arp -a " . $ip;
$status = 0;
$return = [];
exec($cmd, $return, $status);
var_dump($status, $return);
die;
```

If everything went OK, then `$status` should be zero and `$return` may or may not be empty. However if `$status` is *non-zero* then pay attention to what the value of `$return` is, as this will be what your system is telling you is happening when it tries to run your command.

Protip: Pass `exec()` the *full path* to `arp` as-in:

```
#> which arp
/usr/sbin/arp

$cmd = "/usr/sbin/arp -a" . $ip;
```

Also, bear in mind, depending on where the command is being run, `REMOTE_ADDR` may not return anything useful. There are several other ways of obtaining an IP address, which are especially useful if the IP address you need is behind some sort of proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Guess I could take this script a step further.. remember, only works on your local network. will return false if not able to get.

```
function GetMAC() { 
    $cmd = "arp -a " . $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]; 
    $status = 0; 
    $return = []; 
    exec($cmd, $return, $status); 
    if(isset($return[3])) return strtoupper(str_replace("-",":",substr($return[3],24,17))); 
    return false; 
}
```